# Multipart form data ajax request in dojo

Tags: ajax, dojo

I googled a lot but could not find a way to do ajax post request for Multipart formdata enctype form .Can   anybody help

Answer (score -1):

Check out Example 1 in the dojo.xhr documentation: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/xhr.html

A tweaked/shortened version:

```
<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="myForm" data-dojo-id="myForm"
 encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method="">

 <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
    type="text"
    id="name"
    name="name" />

 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">
    Submit
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">
        dojo.xhrPost({
            // The target URL on your webserver:
            url: "#",

            // The form node, which contains the
            // to be transferred form elements:
            form: "myForm",

            // Event handler on successful call:
            load: function(response, ioArgs){
                // do something
            }
        });
    </script>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: any way i found solution by using    dojo.io.iframe.send({
         url:"http://localhost:8080/dojoupload/FileUploader", 
           form: _newForm,
           handleAs: "json",
           handle: dojo.hitch(this,"displayPost")
       });

Comment: I am using   <input name="uploadedfile" multiple="true" type="file" id="uploader" dojoType="dojox.form.Uploader" label="Select Some Files"> to upload file is there a way i can choose one file and send to server     to   process